# java swaping mix and max array out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays

Why does my array become out of bounds when I am swapping largest and smallest numbers places using methods and how can I fix this so I don't get error because the numbers swap places but I get the error.

```
    class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = new int[11];
        {
            array[0] = 1;
            array[1] = 2;
            array[2] = 3;
            array[3] = 4;
            array[4] = 5;
            array[5] = -1;
            array[6] = -2;
            array[7] = -3;
            array[8] = -4;
            array[9] = -5;
            array[10] = -6;
            swapMinMaxBetter(array);
            max(array);
            min(array);
        }
    }
        public static int min(int[] array) {
            int smallest = array[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] < smallest) {
                    smallest = array[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("MIN: " + smallest);
            return smallest;
        }
        public static int max(int[] array) {
            int largest = array[0];

            for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (array[i] > largest) {
                    largest = array[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("MAX: " + largest);
            return largest;
        }
        public static void swap(int[] array, int m, int n) {
            int temp = array[m];
            array[m] = array[n];
            array[n] = temp;
        }
        public static void swapMinMaxBetter(int[] array) {
            int smallest = min(array);
            int largest = max(array);
            swap(array, smallest, largest);
        }
    }
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -6
    at HelloWorld.swap(HelloWorld.java:44)
    at HelloWorld.swapMinMaxBetter(HelloWorld.java:51)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:17)
```

Comment: You call int largest = max(array);

max() returns the largest number, not the index, so when you do swap(), you are passing in m and n like they are indexes but they are the values.

Comment: You checked my answer as correct, did this work for you?

Comment: Yes it works thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your min() and max() functions return the value and not the index, try this:

```
class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[11];
    {
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;
        array[2] = 3;
        array[3] = 4;
        array[4] = 5;
        array[5] = -1;
        array[6] = -2;
        array[7] = -3;
        array[8] = -4;
        array[9] = -5;
        array[10] = -6;
        swapMinMaxBetter(array);
        max(array);
        min(array);
    }
}
    public static int min(int[] array) {
        int smallest = array[0];
        int smallestIndex = 0

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < smallest) {
                smallest = array[i];
                smallestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("MIN: " + smallest);
        return smallestIndex;
    }
    public static int max(int[] array) {
        int largest = array[0];
        int largestIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > largest) {
                largest = array[i];
                largestIndex = i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("MAX: " + largest);
        return largestIndex;
    }
    public static void swap(int[] array, int m, int n) {
        int temp = array[m];
        array[m] = array[n];
        array[n] = temp;
    }
    public static void swapMinMaxBetter(int[] array) {
        int smallest = min(array);
        int largest = max(array);
        swap(array, smallest, largest);
    }
}
```